# How to save a ViewModel's array in Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

My ViewModel looks like

```
public class MyVm
{
    public List<string> MyList{get;set;}
}
```

In my .chstml file I'd like to populate this via a JavaScript array

How do I do this

This is my effort

```
@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.MyList)
<script>
    var myJsList = ["this", "that"];
    document.getElementById("MyList").value = myJsList;
</script>
```

The issue is when I click the save button, my controller shows

```
public ActionResult Save(MyVm model)
{
    //model.MyList is null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store a complex type such as a `List<string>` in a single hidden input. You will need multiple hidden fields instead. So for example you could have a container for those hidden fields:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

into which you will inject the corresponding hidden fields dynamically depending on the value stored in your javascript string array:

```
<script>
    var myJsList = ["this", "that"];
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    for (var i = 0; i < myJsList.length; i++) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "MyList[" + i + "]");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", myJsList[i]);
        container.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
</script>
```

so basically you will end up with the following DOM:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="hidden" name="MyList[0]" value="this" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MyList[1]" value="that" />
</div>
```

which is what you are aiming at if you want the standard ASP.NET MVC model binder to hydrate those values to a `List<string>` into your view model.

Comment: This is going to take me a little while to get my head round. I know the ethos of the website so will mark as answer but please give me a little time to undertsand

Comment: Thank you for this. This is starting to make sense. I guess it brings up another question in what if it were a List<Person>, where Person has Name (string) and Age (int) properties. Would it be `<input type="hidden" name="MyList[0].Name" value="Jon" /><input type="hidden" name="MyList[0].Age" value="50" />`

Comment: Yeap, that's exactly how the hidden fields should be named for the model binding to work correctly.

Comment: Would it matter if the property was List<IPerson> where IPerson is an interface and not a class?